# Hiking map for Hokkaido and/or other resources

Tags: hiking, backpacking, backcountry, maps

I plan to go hiking in Hokkaido next spring. I'd like to hike two weeks and to keep away from the cities during this time.

I'd like to visit Daisetsuzan Park and Shiretoko Park. I've read about Daisetsuzan grand traverse, but with 55km it's far too short for what I want (in 2 weeks I'd like to cover at least 300km or 400km). I'm a seasoned hiker and I know myself and my capacities well. Ideally, I'd like to cross the island from one point to the other.

Are there some good resources online? Ideally I'd like some online maps (like [this map of Switzerland](https://map.wanderland.ch/) for example) to help me define my itinerary*. Other resources like detailed blogs are also welcome, or personnal information if you have some. I don't speak japanese at all.

* I've seen opencyclemap maps, but they are not so detailed

Comment: I don't do any of this type of traveling, so I can't really help. I did find something at [mountainstamp.com](http://www.mountainstamp.com/Japan%20pages/Hokkaido_region_Hauptseite.html). Could this type of thing be helpful?

Comment: Do any answers on [this question](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/704/looking-for-a-topographical-map-resource?rq=1) help at all?

Comment: Yes! Using [this answer](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/709/12266], I've found [this online map](http://maps.gsi.go.jp/#15/43.390953/142.635283/&base=std&ls=std&disp=1&vs=c1j0l0u0f0). It's not perfect (the names are only in japanese and I can't trace a GPX track), but it is a good start.

Comment: I'm so glad! I checked for a way to turn that into English and found, on the same site, [Maps of Japan to be more easily understandable for overseas visitors](http://www.gsi.go.jp/kokusaikoryu/kokusaikoryu-e30098.html). It has a list of rules to assist in translation, and also [Lists of Map Symbols for our Overseas Visitors](http://www.gsi.go.jp/common/000139534.pdf). Hopefully this will help with the language part. At least I think it's worth checking out. I don't know what a GPX track is, so you still might not get everything you need, but I hope you do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thansk to [Sue's comment](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15087/hiking-map-for-hokkaido-and-or-other-resources?noredirect=1#comment38926_15087) and using [this answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/709/12266):

> Check this link out: [FREE topographic maps and research
>   tools](http://peaklist.org/misc/links_to_map_resources.html).

I've found [this online map](http://maps.gsi.go.jp):

[image]

It's not perfect (the names are only in japanese and I can't trace a GPX track), but it is a good start.

If anyone (maybe with some knwoledge of japanese) find it is possible to make a GPX track on this map, the information is welcome.